# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unexpected token < - Implementing systemJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, systemjs

I'm trying to integrate systemJS in my current project which is using angular 1.5 syntax. I want to load sum.js file using system js , which in turn calls reduce.js and add.js using commonJS syntax .
currently all the build files are being generated though gulp.

I'm not using any transpiler because as per my understanding they are needed for ES6.

My Systemjs.config.js file looks like this:

```
   console.log("in systemjs config");

    SystemJS.config({
      map: {
        'wire': 'app/Test/js'
      },
      packages: {
        'wire': {
            main: './sum.js' 
                }
      }
     }
 });

SystemJS.import('wire').then(function(wire) {
    console.log('Module', wire);
});
console.log("end of systemjs config");
```

sum.js file has this content:

```
console.log("inside sum file first line");
var reduce = require("./reduce");
var add = require("./add");
function sum(list){
    return reduce(list, add, 0);
};
module.exports = sum;
console.log("inside sum file");
```

reduce.js has this content:

```
function reduce(list, iteratee, memo) {
    list.forEach(function (item) {
        memo = iteratee(item, memo);
    });
    return memo;
}
module.exports = reduce;
```

add.js looks like this:

```
function add(a,b){
    return a + b;
}
module.exports = add;
```

I can see system JS file being loaded in debugger(network tab) but not sum.js file, neither i can see any console message , which I have added in sum.js for debugging.
I think I'm missing some basic configuration steps. Please help

Comment: What is the unexpected token? In which file?